Is this question on child sexuality purely subjective?
I'm uncertain if this question should be closed as primarily opinion based. Both of the answers included at the bottom seem to be somewhat low quality and I'm sceptical that any superior answers can be provided. Why should this question be kept open?
Related:
How to distinguish social psychology from opinion-based questions?

I don't think it warrants closing as primarily opinion based. The question can be elaborated surely, but I do not feel the question should be evaluated based on the current answers posted.

In what way do you think it could be elaborated upon?

By resolving (adding initial research, and qualifying where needed) the statements (at times implicit), e.g. "We remove children from anything that is sex related", "it might be something more than cultural", "no one thinks it's wrong to send a 5 year old to a martial arts class", ...
